# Incremental Copy data from PostgreSql to Blob

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am currently working on PostgreSql, and working to move Incremental data from PostgresDb to Blob, please help me with the solution, previously tried doing copy tool templates but no use.

I want to copy data incrementally from PostgreSql to Azure Blob.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't make your problem sufficiently clear for someone to help you.

Comment: Hi Paul, I am having some data in postgresql, and on a daily basis that data increases, so it is not possible for me to add data daily, so help me with a way to move data automatically to Blob, Increamentally.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the solution in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview#delta-data-loading-from-database-by-using-a-watermark) to define a watermark in your source database which has the last updated time stamp or an incrementing key.

1.**Select the watermark column.** Select one column in the source data store, which can be used to slice the new or updated records for every run. Normally, the data in this selected column (for example, last_modify_time or ID) keeps increasing when rows are created or updated.

2.**Configure the query sql in copy activity.**

Such as `select * from table where modifyTime between 2019.3.27 and 2019.3.28`

[image]

3.**Create a schedule trigger to run your pipeline and copy activity.** Please see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger). You could trigger it every day to copy the data of yesterday incrementally.

[image]

Comment: @SaiAkhil Not sure what you meaning. My solution already has loaded the modified data into the destination. It just loads the modified date during yesterday.

Comment: @SaiAkhil Hi,any progress? Does my answer helps you?